# killall gives me `no process found ` but ps

Tags: linux, process, kill, ps

Could somebody explain to me the difference between `kill` and `killall`? Why doesn't `killall` see what `ps` shows?

```
# ps aux |grep db2
root      1123  0.0  0.8 841300 33956 pts/1    Sl   11:48   0:00 db2wdog                                         
db2inst1  1125  0.0  3.5 2879496 143616 pts/1  Sl   11:48   0:02 db2sysc                                        
root      1126  0.0  0.6 579156 27840 pts/1    S    11:48   0:00 db2ckpwd                                        
root      1127  0.0  0.6 579156 27828 pts/1    S    11:48   0:00 db2ckpwd                                        
root      1128  0.0  0.6 579156 27828 pts/1    S    11:48   0:00 db2ckpwd 

# killall db2ckpwd
db2ckpwd: no process found

# kill -9 1126
# kill -9 1127
# kill -9 1128
```

System is SuSe 11.3 (64 bit); kernel 2.6.34-12; procps version 3.2.8; killall from PSmisc 22.7; kill from GNU coreutils 7.1

Comment: **Never** kill processes with SIGKILL (-9).

Comment: What to do then when a process needs to terminated?

Comment: This is the very, very last resort.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Is this on Linux?

There are actually a few subtly different versions of the command name that are used by `ps`, `killall`, etc.

The two main variants are: 1) the long command name, which is what you get when you run `ps u`; and 2) the short command name, which is what you get when you run `ps` without any flags.

Probably the biggest difference happens if your program is a shell script or anything that requires an interpreter, e.g. Python, Java, etc.

Here's a really trivial script that demonstrates the difference.  I called it `mycat`:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat
```

After running it, here's the two different types of `ps`.

Firstly, without `u`:

```
$ ps -p 5290
  PID TTY      ... CMD
 5290 pts/6    ... mycat
```

Secondly, with `u`:

```
$ ps u 5290
USER       PID ... COMMAND
mikel     5290 ... /bin/sh /home/mikel/bin/mycat
```

Note how the second version starts with `/bin/sh`?

Now, as far as I can tell, `killall` actually reads `/proc/<pid>/stat`, and grabs the second word in between the parens as the command name, so that's really what you need to be specifying when you run `killall`.  Logically, that should be the same as what `ps` without the `u` flag says, but it would be a good idea to check.

Things to check:

1. what does `cat /proc/<pid>/stat` say the command name is?
2. what does `ps -e | grep db2` say the command name is?
3. do `ps -e | grep db2` and `ps au | grep db2` show the same command name?

---

**Notes**

If you're using other ps flags too, then you might find it simpler to use `ps -o comm` to see the short name and `ps -o cmd` to see the long name.

You also might find `pkill` a better alternative.  In particular, `pkill -f` tries to match using the full command name, i.e. the command name as printed by `ps u` or `ps -o cmd`.

Comment: very good explanation. And I guess you were right the first time. `ps -e |grep db2 gives me `3084 ?        00:00:00 db2syscr` and ps aux |grep db2 gives me `root      3084  0.0  0.6 579292 28304 ?        S    13:02   0:00 db2ckpwd`. Could comment on that. I am bit lost.

Comment: I'm not sure.  It's possible that the program is changing its name.  Do you know how it's being run?  What does `ls -l /proc/3084/exe` say?  What about `which` or `whence` or `type` to find the file and then `ls` and `type` to see if it's a symlink or a script or a binary?

Comment: ls -l /proc/3084/exe gives us `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun  6 16:49 /proc/3084/exe -> /var/lib/db2/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2syscr`

Comment: ls -l /var/lib/db2/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2syscr gives me `-r-sr-s--- 1 root db2iadm1 147K Feb  1 23:32 /var/lib/db2/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2syscr*`

Comment: type gives me /var/lib/db2/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2syscr `/var/lib/db2/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2syscr is /var/lib/db2/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2syscr`

Comment: Good example is a [`gnome-caluclator`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Calculator) which I was not able to kill with neither [`killall`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall) nor [`pkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) because it is called `gnome-calculato` ([sic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic)!).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint about pkill. It's MUCH better suited for my task than killall, which I thought I knew how to use - but suddenly stopped working like intended when I upgraded my host system from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. The "Things to check" didn't give any insights about what's wrong, but pkill -f works.

Answer (score 10):

`killall` tries to match on a process name (but is not really that good at the matching part).

And since `ps | grep` and `ps | grep | kill` does a much better job, someone simplified this and created `pgrep` and `pkill`. Read that commands like `ps grep` and `ps kill`, since that command first `ps` then `grep` and if wanted kills.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem but `/proc/<pid>/stat` contained the expected string. By using strace I could see that killall also accessed `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`.

I continued to investigate using gdb to find that in my case it failed on a check of my command to the full command including all args found in `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`. It seemed like that path of the code triggered due to the filename being longer than 15 chars (which is a hardcoded value in the source of killall). I didn't fully investigate if I could somehow getting it to work with killall.

But as mentioned in other comments here pkill is a better alternative that does not have the same issues.

The source code of `pkill` can be found here https://github.com/acg/psmisc for the interested.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16 systems the /proc/*pid*/stat will contain the name of the thread (which a program can via *pthread_setname_np* system call.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases `kill PID` will work.

To identify the PID use `pgrep <application name>`

If you have kill a application like Google Chrome which is running with multiple PIDs

i would use `killall "Google Chrome"` which will basically force quit the application by killing all the PIDs.

*conclusion* : If you have a multiple PIDs for application try killall, if only one PID is present kill and killall will work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the name of the main thread with pthread_setname_np call will also cause killall and other command to fail even if the name of the process will stay the same with ps:

```
pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "Main_thread");
```

Will result in:

```
# killall processname
processname: no process found
```

You will be able to see the name see the real name used by killall with pgrep:

```
# pgrep -fl processname
1234 Main_thread
```